# Second column Auto Increment from last inserted phpmyadmin

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, multiple-columns, increment, auto

I have a table of generated invoice numbers (currently ID) which are type Primary Key AI.

I now want to add another/multiple users to the table list of which they all generate sequentially from their last invoice number. Primary Key will now be as ID AI Primary but I want to add a another column which will now be the invoice number.

I've been scratching my head for a few days over this, the only way I can think is to check the last invoice number where email matches and add increment by 1 but is that even doable? What's the best approach to this?

```
 | ID       | Invoice Number | email |
 | -------- | --------      | -------- |
 | 1        | 120111        |some@email.co.uk |
 | 2        | 120111        |another@email.co.uk |
 | 3        | 120112        |some@email.co.uk |
 | 4        | 120112        |another@email.co.uk |
 | 6        | 120113        |another@email.co.uk |
 | 7        | 120114        |another@email.co.uk |
 | 8        | 120115        |another@email.co.uk |
 | 9        | 120116        |another@email.co.uk |
 | 10       | 120113        |some@email.co.uk |
```

I've tried getting last inserted but the only way I can do this is to insert then check which is messy.